# Automatically show selected value

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

There are two separate tables for users and roles. So for the roles would have a number between 1~7 and would have different roles depending on each users. We are trying to create a dropdown for when the selected role when registering would be updated to the users table. My problem is, we are currently showing the lists of role but we are not being able to show the current role updated to the current user. There are no forms involved. We are just fetching data from the database.

```
<?php
    $admin_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $roles = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM roles ");
    $selected_role = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role=r.role_id WHERE id=$admin_id ");
?>
<?php
    while($total_roles = mysqli_fetch_array($roles)){

?>
        <option selected="" value="<?php echo $total_roles['role_id']?>" ><?php echo $total_roles['role'] ?></option>

<?php
    }
?>
```

I tried adding in,

```
<option selected="<?php $selected_role['role'] ?>" value="<?php echo $total_roles['role_id']?>" ><?php echo $total_roles['role'] ?></option>
```

It doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Please format your code blocks properly - not with indentation that forces us to scroll a mile sideways first.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" - Please have a look at [ask]. What is not working? Are you getting errors? Did you check the error logs? What is the expected output?

Comment: Of course `$selected_role['role']` does not work, because `$selected_role` is not even an array, it is the result of your mysqli_query call. You need to _fetch_ the data out of the result set first of all.

Comment: **BIG HINT:** `session_start()`

Comment: Also you are applying the `selected` attribute to each of the options. You should write some logic to determine if the current role in the loop matches the role set in the database for the specific user

Comment: ...what CBroe said. And isn't that obvious, since you're already fetching the data correctly from the $roles data...you need to do something similar with the second dataset.

Comment: (Plus, `<?php $somevar; ?>` doesn't actually do anything. If you wanted to create output at this point, this is missing an echo/print, or needs to use `<?=`)

Comment: You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating any values into the query.

Comment: Also looks like you are missing a connection to the database

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the check if the current role is equal to the role that is gathered in the While loop.
Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Which means the database is at risk. If you are willing to learn more about SQL Injection please use [THIS](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) reference.

```
<?php
session_start();

$admin_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$roles = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM roles");


// Prevent SQL injection
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role=r.role_id WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $admin_id);
$stmt->execute();
$selected_role = $stmt->fetch_row();
while ($total_roles = mysqli_fetch_array($roles)) {
    echo "<option ";
    if (!empty($selected_role) && $selected_role['role_id'] === $total_roles['role_id']) {
        echo "selected='selected' ";
    }
    echo "value='".$total_roles['role_id']."'>".$total_roles['role']."</option>";
}
```